# Updating multiple JTextFields with a single call using a Listener

Tags: java, listener, deep-copy

With JButtons, I am able to create one AbstractAction and associate it with a number of JButtons allowing me to enable/disable many buttons with 1 command.

I would like to have the similar ability but with updating the value of a number of JTextFields with a single call. Unfortunately I have not been able to determine what type of Actions/Listeners or whatever to use.

The following is a rudimentary code sample that creates 2 JFrames. One frame has a JButton and a JTextField. The second frame just has a JTextField.

Whether the button is clicked or Return is hit within the JTextfield, the counter will increment and only appear within the JTextField on frame1. Although hitting enter within the JTextField on frame 2, the value still only updates on frame 1.

The prime objective is to update the JTextField on both frames via the doData() BUT to do it via some Action or Listener or some other means than directly referencing the JTextField itself.

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class DetachedUpdate 
    {
      JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
      int x = 1;
      public static void main(final String args[]) 
      {
          DetachedUpdate myApp = new DetachedUpdate();
          myApp.field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("actionPerformed()");
                    myApp.doData();
                }
            });
          buildFrame1(myApp.field1, myApp);
          buildFrame2(myApp.field1, myApp);
      }

      public void doData()
      {
          System.out.println("doData()");
          field1.setText(new Integer(x++).toString());
      }

      public static void buildFrame1(JTextField txtField, DetachedUpdate x)
      {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
            toolbar.setRollover(true);

            JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");

            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("actionPerformed()");
                    x.doData();
                }
            });

            toolbar.add(button1);
            toolbar.add(txtField);
            Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      public static void buildFrame2(JTextField txtField, DetachedUpdate x)
      {
          JTextField newField = new JTextField();

            ActionListener[] listeners = txtField.getActionListeners();  
            for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++)
            {
                newField.addActionListener(listeners[i]);
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolBar Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
            toolbar.setRollover(true);

            JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");

            toolbar.add(newField);
            Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `actionPerformed` itself is used for both field, but this will not automagically synchronise the fields content. Look into `DocumentListener` and try using the same DocumentListener for both.

Comment: I reviewed the DocumentListener prior to posting and my interpretation was that it pertained to managing the data being inserted by the user and not used for making programmatic updates to the field. I will look more into it though.

Comment: Otherwise, you could introduce a new class that would contain a list of JTextField to update, and when the `actionPerformed` occurs, you call a method like `updateComponents(field.getText())`. I do not think "sharing" listeners is a good practice.